# How in Dart Editor perform operation "Outline File" (Alt+O) with results sorted alphabetically instead of unsorted order?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

How in Dart Editor perform operation `Outline File` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) with results sorted alphabetically instead of unsorted order?

I often work with  the libraries that contains a lot of classes in one file.  Also  sometimes exists classes that consists from a lot of members.

But when I want examine file structure (outline file) I can not find some information in fast way because Editor display data in natural order (i.e. unsorted).

It is possible to turn  on some option that information will be sorted alphabetically?

Also how display this information in a separate window but not in the popup window?

I'm not familiar with the peculiarities of working with this Editor, and so I asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the Outline pane by clicking `Tools -> Outline`. In the Outline pane there is an "A-Z" button that will toggle between sorting the members in natural order and alphabetical order.